# Python to sort and count the uniq names from the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, counting

I'm trying to read the log file in Linux `/var/log/messages` for a line having special pattern of strings which I have given below. From this line pattern I'm looking at the e-mail address for the user, like `rajeshm@noi-rajeshm.fox.com` and using the `str.partition()` method I'm separating it into two parts as a list index, and taking the first one further getting that split into a list for the ease of taking last index value, which is the user ID and that's working fine.

Saying that I'm able to get the list of users and total count but I need to count the occurrence of each user and print the `user_name: Count`, so the key and value.

> Nov 28 09:00:08 foxopt210 rshd[6157]: pam_rhosts(rsh:auth): allowed
>   access to rajeshm@noi-rajeshm.fox.com as rajeshm

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
f= open("/var/log/messages")
count = 0
for line in f:
  if "allowed access"  in line:
    count+=1
    user_id = line.partition('@')[0]
    user_id = user_id.split()[-1]
    print(user_id)
f.close()
print("--------------------")
print("Total Count :" ,count)
```

The current code is working as below:

```
bash-4.1$ ./log.py | tail
navit
akaul
akaul
pankaja
vishalm
vishalm
rajeshm
rajeshm
--------------------
Total Count : 790
```

While googling around I get the idea of using dictionary for this
purpose and it's working as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from collections import Counter
f= open("/var/log/messages")
count = 0
dictionary = {}
for line in f:
  if "allowed access"  in line:
    user_id = line.partition('@')[0]
    user_count = user_id.split()[-1]
    if user_count in dictionary:
        dictionary[user_count] += 1
    else:
       dictionary[user_count] = 1
for user_count, occurences in dictionary.items():
    print(user_count, ':', occurences)
```

And my output is as desired:

```
bash-4.1$ ./log2.py
rajeshm : 5
navit : 780
akaul : 2
pankaja : 1
vishalm : 2
```

I'm just looking if there is a better way around for this exercise.

Comment: `dictionary = collections.Counter(line.partition('@')[0].rsplit(None, 1)[-1] for line in f if 'allowed access' in line)`, then `for user_count, count in dictionary.most_common(): print(user_count, count, sep=':')`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thnx for your inputs.. i'll try this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When counting things, it's easier to use the [`collections.Counter()` class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). I'd encapsulate parsing the lines into a generator here:

```
def users_accessed(fileobj):
    for line in fileobj:
        if 'allowed access' in line:
            yield line.partition('@')[0].rsplit(None, 1)[-1]
```

and pass this to the `Counter()` object:

```
from collections import Counter

with open("/var/log/messages") as f:
    access_counts = Counter(users_accessed(f))

for userid, count in access_counts.most_common():
    print(userid, count, sep=':')
```

This uses the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to provide sorted output (most common to least).

Comment: thnx aagain.. this is nice one, will try and revert you on the results.

Comment: @Martin .. this is working fine, thnx.. can you please explain the `(None, 1)` and yeild Keywords .

Comment: @Karn: `str.rsplit(None)`  is the same as `str.rsplit()`; splitting on aribtary whitespace. `str.rsplit()` takes a second argument that limits the number of splits, so `str.rsplit(None, 1)` splits just *once* on whitespace, counting from the right. By splitting just once you keep it more efficient, there is no point in splitting further as you ignore the rest of the results.

Comment: @Karn: `yield` makes something a generator function, see [What does the "yield" keyword do?](//stackoverflow.com/q/231767)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the regular expression and can do this:

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=as\s)\w.+'
occurrence={}

with open("/var/log/messages") as f:
    for line in f:
        search=re.search(pattern,line).group()

        if  search not in occurrence:
            occurrence[search]=1
        else:
            occurrence[search]=occurrence.get(search)+1

print(occurrence)
```

> Just for fun one line logic:

```
import re
pattern=r'(?<=as\s)\w.+'
new={}
[new.__setitem__(re.search(pattern, line).group(), 1) if re.search(pattern, line).group() not in new  else new.__setitem__(re.search(pattern, line).group(), new.get(re.search(pattern, line).group()) + 1) for line in open('legend.txt','r')]

print(new)
```